# theorem 4-9 Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: differential-forms

From *Calculus On Manifolds* by Spivak

If $f\colon\,\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable, then $f^*(h\, dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n)=(\det f')\cdot(h\circ f)\,dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n$

Proof: Since $f^*(h\, dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n)=(h\circ f)f^*(dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n)$ it suffices to show that

$$f^*(dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n)=(\det f')\,dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n.$$

Let $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix of $f'(p)$.
(We shall omit "p" in $dx^1_p\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n_p$ if it causes no confusion).

$$\begin{align}f^*(dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n)(e_1,...e_n)&=\\
&=(dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n)(f_*e_1,\dots, f_*e_n)=\\
&=(dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i1}e_i,\dots,\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{in}e_i\right)=\\
&=\det(a_{ij})\,(dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n)(e_1,...e_n)
\end{align}$$

My question is how $f_*e_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i1}e_i$?

I know  $f_*(v_p)=(Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}=f(p)+Df(p)(v)$.

Comment: Your last sentence ("I know ... ") is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\colon V\to W$. Choose a basis $e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n$ of $V$ and $u_1, \dots, u_n$ of $W$. We *define* the matrix $(a_{ij})$ of $A$ (with respect to the chosen bases) such that
$$A(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} u_i$$
This is the definition – obviously one needs to show that it makes sense (i.e. numbers $a_{ij}$ exists and are determined uniquely).

In your question $A=f_*=Df_p$ is the derivative, i.e. a linear map
$$Df_p\colon T_p\mathbb R^n\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb R^n.$$

Choosing a basis $e_{1,p}, \dots, e_{n, p}$ for $T_p\mathbb R^n$ and $e_{1,f(p)}, \dots, e_{n, f(p)}$ for $T_{f(p)}\mathbb R^n$ *(this nomenclature may be a bit confusing)* your equation becomes the obvious

$$f_*(e_{j,p}) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} e_{i, f(p)}.$$

And this is what you should get – you will see this if you add subscripts to $dx^i$ as well.

Edit: I should have said this explicitly, as Ted Shifrin did – the last statement of your question is wrong. Such addition doesn't make sense in general – $f(p)$ is a *point of the target manifold* and $Df_p(v)$ is a *vector tangent to the manifold*.

Comment: Actually in spivak,they wrote  for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$,$ Df(p):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.A minor modification produce a linear transformation $f_*:\mathbb{R}^n_{(p)} \to \mathbb{R}^m_{f(p)}$ defined by $f_*(v_p)=(Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}$

Comment: so i thought $f_*(e_1)_p=(Df(p)(e_1))_{f(p)}$ i have $Df(p)(e_1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i1}e_i$    So  $f_*(e_1)_p=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i1}e_i)_{f(p)}$ where i am wrong?

Comment: Nowhere – the last equation is right.

Comment: but what should i do with that subscript f(p)?U got $f_*(e_1)_p=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i1}e_i$ and i got  $f_*(e_1)_p=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i1}e_i)_{f(p)}$

Comment: I have edited the answer, hope it's less confusing now.